# Element's animation doesn't work after wrapping it with div

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

HTML:
Primary animation on load works, also animation on *cards:hover* DOES work without .*div insidecard*.
I need this *.insidecard* to wrap elements to make sure the last card won't go to the next line and keep it responsive.

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="showcards">Show Cards</div> 
    <div class="insidecard">
        <img class="insidecard01" src="img/cards/01.jpg">
        <img class="insidecard02" src="img/cards/03.jpg">
        <img class="insidecard03" src="img/cards/02.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's CSS. Animation Keyframes are fine, so I guess no need to show them.

```
    .cards {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .insidecard {
      width: 600px;
      display: block;
    }
    .cards:hover > .insidecard02 {
      animation: cardsout02 0.6s linear;
    }
    .cards:hover > .insidecard03 {
      -webkit-animation: cardsout03 0.6s linear;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure changed, now your image elements are not children of `.cards` anymore, so change the CSS like so

```
.cards:hover .insidecard02 {
  animation: cardsout02 0.6s linear;
}
.cards:hover  .insidecard03 {
  -webkit-animation: cardsout03 0.6s linear;
}
```

removing the child combinator `>`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be like

```
.cards:hover > .insidecard > .insidecard02{
    // Your animation here
}
```

It's selecting it's child with a class *insidecard* with a child *insidecard02*. The **>** is used for selecting children of a parent only, not the children of it's children.

You can read that more in here [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)